# User login script: Users can login with any username and password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, login-script

I am trying to make a simple user - login system. However, I have everything with sessions, and stuff working but the user login is not working with the database. I can input any username and password and login.

Here is my login page:

```
<?php
session_start();


$db_host = "localhost";             // Place the database host here
$db_username = "data_user";  // Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "password";          // Place the password for the MySQL  database here
$db_name = "database_name";     // Place the name for the MySQL database here

if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
// MySQL Connection
$db_link = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql. Make sure you have correctly inputed your host, username, and password.");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database could be found.");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

// MySQL Query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ");

if(!$result) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = '<span style="color:red">Login Failed</span>';
} else 
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
    mysql_close($db_link);
}
header('Location: ./')
?>
```

I am using Bootstraps login. So this is my login html:

```
                <div id="login" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form class="form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Username</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input name="username" type="text" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is the very basic login using bootstrap. I got the log out working fine so thats good, however anyways can anyone explain to me why it is not connected to the database and you can login with any username and password that you can imagine?

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions in new code.

Comment: You can also debug a lot of this yourself. Figure out what `$result` is returning and why.

Comment: This also smells like you have plaintext passwords in your database. There will be people who can't wait to get their hands on it! Apologies though if you are hashing client-side and sending the result.

Comment: Actually your right lc. I'm trying to do one thing at a time. The database only consist of two tables. Users & ranks. The users only have 3, id, username, password.

After I get this working I will move on to adding the emails, and password encryption.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!$result) {
```

Is a wrong check. This will return valid even if there are no rows. It will only result false if the query failed to execute. You should check for row count, possibly with **[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)**.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows!=1)
{
echo "Bad U/P";
}
```

Note: Its time you stop using **mysql_*** functions and move to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 2):

The SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'
```

will work at the line value will of `$result` will not be false.

It means that a result set has no rows in the event of an invalid username/password pair.

Comment: So what should I have instead?

Comment: For a start use either mysqli functions or PDO. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Use **PDO**: [Quick tutorial »](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT `password` FROM `table` WHERE `username` = ?" );

$sth->execute( array( $username ) );

$returned_password = $sth->fetchColumn;
```

... and by doing the query like that, means you don't need to `WHERE password`, means you don't need to index the `password` column (efficiency speaking).

--

From the result, compare with user inputted password:

```
if ( $returned_password == $password )
    // OK
else
    // NOT OK
```

... or if you previously store the password in some hash value which is a very good practice:

```
if ( $returned_password == md5( $password ) )
    // OK
else
    // NOT OK
```

... as for why your current script is allowing any login, see @Hanky Panky ㇱ's answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Just an advice, do not use md5.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly,

but did you actually create the database with the name "database_name"  and user "data_user" ?

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "data_user";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "database_name";
```

I believe you have not put in the correct details for the database. Please do so if not and let us know.

Comment: Lol, i had just placed those there for stack overflow. Not gonna give out my password and such :P

Comment: sure! i just wanted to highlight it :) i thought so because of the line "however anyways can anyone explain to me why it is not connected to the database" in your question

Answer (score -2):

`print_r($row);`

what that display when you print $row row does that return the data

Comment: That gives error:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/pardyco/public_html/login.php on line 22

Answer (score -3):

try editing the following line

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
```

to

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row[0]['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
```

just because you have used mysql_fetch_assoc the resultant array will be an associative array of rows and columns.

Comment: No, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns one row.

Comment: No, mysql_fetch_array will return 1 row every time you use it in a loop for the same resultset. But mysql_fetch_assoc is an associative array of all the rows and columns selected by the select query.

Comment: Sir, if you see the exmaple then you will find that while is used to parse through the mysql_fetch_assoc; If you write $result = mysql_fetch_assoc; then $result is complete associative array wherease in mysql_fetch_array it will now be.

Comment: and in the problem code you can see that while is not used so the array $result will be associative with respect to rows and column and not just just.

Comment: So somehow the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function is supposed to understand if it is in a loop or not? That doesn't make any sense.